# Android Layout : LinearLayout equal size circles

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

I am trying to create the layout as seen below.

[image]

So far I have the following, however I'm afraid that, based on the screen resolution, the circles could become skewed since I'm hardcoding the height on the main container.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutAvatarItem1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_drawable_color_1">

        <CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgAvatarItem1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/general_content_desc"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/AppRed"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

        <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
            android:id="@+id/imgAvatarLoader1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:indicatorColor="@color/White"
            app:indicatorName="BallPulseIndicator" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutAvatarItem2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_drawable_color_1">

        <CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgAvatarItem2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/general_content_desc"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/AppRed"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

        <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
            android:id="@+id/imgAvatarLoader2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:indicatorColor="@color/White"
            app:indicatorName="BallPulseIndicator" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutAvatarItem3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_drawable_color_1">

        <CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgAvatarItem3"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/general_content_desc"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/AppRed"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

        <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
            android:id="@+id/imgAvatarLoader3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:indicatorColor="@color/White"
            app:indicatorName="BallPulseIndicator" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutAvatarItem4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_drawable_color_1">

        <CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgAvatarItem4"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/general_content_desc"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/AppRed"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

        <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
            android:id="@+id/imgAvatarLoader4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:indicatorColor="@color/White"
            app:indicatorName="BallPulseIndicator" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutAvatarItem5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_drawable_color_1">

        <CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgAvatarItem5"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/general_content_desc"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/AppRed"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

        <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
            android:id="@+id/imgAvatarLoader5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:indicatorColor="@color/White"
            app:indicatorName="BallPulseIndicator" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Circle_drawable_color_1 XML**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/BackgroundColor1" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/AppRed"/>
</shape>
```

How can I create the layout above as a LinearLayout, horizontal orientation with 5 of my Relative layouts within it so that as the screen size grows/shrinks, the circles will also grow/shrink?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve responsive UI, first you need to get rid of hard coded values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" <!-- make it wrap so it can grow -->
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutAvatarItem1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_drawable_color_1">

        <CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgAvatarItem1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
           <!-- make it match, so it stretches to fit -->
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/general_content_desc"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/AppRed"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

        <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
            android:id="@+id/imgAvatarLoader1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:indicatorColor="@color/White"
            app:indicatorName="BallPulseIndicator" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- repeat for other four circles -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Now `LinearLayout` will fit in `width` and divide the items equally based on available screen width, so `width` of your circles are calculated based on screen size, now all you need to do is to match the `height` of the circle to it's `width` in `Java/kotlin`

```
layoutAvatarItem1.post { 
    layoutAvatarItem1.layoutParams = (layoutAvatarItem1.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams).apply { 
        height = width
    }
}
```

**You can do same for all the other circles**

Comment: perfect.  I was WAY over complicating things.  Thank you!